# анимация элементов без animate.css и wow.js

Tags: jquery

Ребят, хочу попробовать это реализовать сам, не хочется подгружать на сайт много ненужного "хлама", но вот в чем загвоздка. Я не могу допереть, как добавить класс к элементам, которые уже находятся в области видимости экрана.
Есть такой вот код, но он добавляет класс "animate" ко всем элементам .sect, не зависимо от того, виден он на экране или нет.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sect=$('.sect');
    if(sect.is(':visible')){
      sect.addClass('animate');
    }
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Решается следующим образом. Получаем текущую позицию элемента, если она выходит за пределы позиции видимого окна, то есть выше или ниже, ничего не делаем, если же позиция элемента входит в видимую область добавляем класс `red`. Все видимые объекты получают класс `red`, невидимые его теряют.

Все это происходит в функции `render()`, при загрузке документа запускаем ее и соответственно при скролле документа `$(document).scroll(render);`. Обход всех элементов (наших дивов) делаем при помощи метода `each()`.

*Конечно же, тут учитываю в области видимости только верхний левый угол дивов, а не весь див целиком, то есть он не станет красным если появляется его нижняя часть при скроллинге снизу вверх, и наоборот.*

Пример залит на [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/gorisuqije/edit?html,output) и тут:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>title</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   var res = $('#result');
   var s = $('#scroll');

   render();
   $(document).scroll(render);


   function render () {

    res.html('windowInnerHeight: ' + $(window).innerHeight() + "<br>windowScrollTop: " + $(window).scrollTop());
    res.html(res.html() + '<br>eq0 offsetTop: ' + $('#scroll div').eq(0).offset().top + 
     '<br>eq9 offsetTop: ' + $('#scroll div').eq(9).offset().top);
    
    
    $('#scroll > div').each(function(index, el) {
     if ( $(el).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop() 
      &&
      $(el).offset().top <= ($(window).innerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()) ) {
      $(this).addClass('red')
     } else {
      $(this).removeClass('red');
     }
     //$(this).toggleClass('red');
    });

    var i = $('#scroll > div').map(function(index, el) {
     //return $(this).css('font-size') !== '17px' ? null : i;
     return $(this).attr('class') == 'red' ? '[red]' : '[ ]';
    });
    console.log(i);
    res.html(res.html() + "<br>Текущие классы: <br>" + $.makeArray(i));
   }
   
  });
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
  * {
   margin: 0;
   position: 0;
  }
  #scroll > div {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
  }
  #result {
   width: 400px;
   height: 150px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   border: 1px solid green;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #scroll > .red {
   border: 2px solid red;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="result"></div>
 <div id="scroll">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```