# Как добавить класс блоку при достижения верха страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пример http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/GobYNK

В примере добавляется класс `fixed fixed-bottom` при прокрутке с любого положения, а нужно только когда прокрутил к самому верху страницы?

И ещё нужно чтобы он удалялся через 3 секунды (т.е добавлялся класс `fixed fixed-top`) как было по умолчанию.

```
<div id="fixedDiv" class="fixed fixed-top">
  Загрузка
</div>


var oldScrollY = 0;
var div = document.getElementById("fixedDiv");

window.onscroll = function() {
var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var dY = scrolled - oldScrollY;

if ( dY < 0 ){
div.className = "fixed fixed-bottom";
} else {
div.className = "fixed fixed-top";
}

oldScrollY = scrolled;
}
```

Comment: возьмите из моего [недавнего примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495574/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-animate-css-%D0%B8-wow-js) `windowScrollTop`, в своем коде сделайте проверку - если  `windowScrollTop == 0`  присвоить класс `fixed fixed-bottom`.

Comment: `if (! scrolled ){`

Comment: Ах, да - про 3 секунды `if (! scrolled ) {
div.className = "fixed fixed-bottom";
setTimeout(function() { div.className = 'fixed' }, 3000);`

Comment: Я совсем запутался. Делаю методом тыка, не выходит http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/VeJNBd

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/09Ls6z7z/

Comment: А без сообщения никак? Это из-за `alert`

Comment: Конечно, его можно выкинуть :)))