# Как на JS или JQ сделать добавление класса к элементу который оказался в видимости экрана?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот скроллим страницу и как только край нужного мне блока появился в видимости браузера, то к нему добавится CSS класс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут я уже отвечал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495574/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-animate-css-%d0%b8-wow-js

Comment: @Jean-Claude тогда надо закрывать как дубликат очевидно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не модератор, мне пофиг.

Comment: @Jean-Claude причем тут модератор? Если это дубль - то значит стоит закрывать как дубль

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так закрывай, мне пофиг дубль или нет.

Comment: @Jean-Claude вы можете нажать "Закрыть" и в причинах выбрать "уже имеет решение" и указать ссылку на решение. Вы как-будто первый день на ресурсе находитесь, чесслово

Comment: Ваше решение вызывает такую ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: @alex-lenk это значит у вас блок не нашло, вы что-то сделали не так